# La différence entre les plusieurs façons de dire « By the way » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, registre-familier, nuance

En étudiant j’ai vu :

• d’ailleurs
• et au passage
• à propos
• sinon

C’est quoi la différence de nuance entre ceux-ci (s’il y’en a, même) ?

Answer (score -2):

« D’ailleurs » sert à introduire une raison en renforcement pour ce qui vient d'être dit. (*En anglais on dirait « in fact »*)

- (*exemple*) Non, je ne sais pas ce qu'il y a sur ce disque ; d'ailleurs, je ne l'ai même pas sorti de son emballage pour l'instant.

« D'ailleurs » ne convient pas pour traduire « by the way ».

« Et au passage » ne correspond pas très bien  à   « by the way » ;  des locutions correctes sont les suivantes  ;

- au fait, à propos, incidemment, en passant

« Sinon » ne convient pas non plus.